# Bootstrap5.3 | react js 18 | SCSS overwrite _variables | [postcss] [sass] Undefined mixin

Tags: reactjs, sass, bootstrap-5, scss-mixins, bootstrap-themes

Hi i want to overwrite bs5 variables, i copied bs5 default variables file from this link https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_variables.scss

when i pasted this code in my custom file i got the error defined in below screeshot

[image]

my App.scss file look like below

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  src: url(../public/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.ttf) format('truetype');
}

.wrapper{
  padding-right:0px !important;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
}
.wrapper {
  .row-wrapper{
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
  }
}
.text-xs {
  font-size: .7rem;
}
@import url('./_variables.scss');
@import url('./Header.scss');
@import url('./Sidebar.scss');
@import url('./Dashboard.scss');
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

looking forward to anyone resolve this issue, thanks.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). And also please edit the title of your question so it's an actual question. The name and version of the libs you use should be specified either in the tags or body of your question, not in the title.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected: you are using a mixin that you did not import before usage.

First thing is that you don't need - and should not - copy the variables source. You should `@use` the Bootstrap module like any other SASS module, and configure it like any SASS module that supports configuration.

Typically, would you want to replace the `$white` variable, you would do:

```
@use "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap" with (
  $white: black
);
```

I strongly recommend that you read the documentation of SASS before going further. You use `@import` that is deprecated, and you seem to not quite understand how SASS works and what a SASS module is.

This documentation especially: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables/#configuring-modules

But really, the whole documentation. You are using `@import` which is deprecated in favor of `@use` so I suspect you need some update on how SASS evolved this last 10 years.

Edit: Here is the link to the official SASS documentation that recommends not using `@import` anymore: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import/

Comment: Hello.  Are you saying that the [official BS documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/) requires modification?  I have done a little bit of messing around according to this documentation and seems to work just fine.  When you say "using @import is deprecated", what does it mean, exactly?

Comment: Bootstrap documentation may need update. Definitely. They still recommend `@import` even though SASS documentation clearly establishes that it should not be used anymore: "The Sass team discourages the continued use of the @import rule. Sass will gradually phase it out over the next few years, and eventually remove it from the language entirely." https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import/