# How to Override the Bootstrap Default Styles in a Svelte/SvelteKit Webapp?

Tags: bootstrap-5, svelte, sveltekit

I have a newly created Svelte app that is working well with Bootstrap5, but I've been unsuccessful in my attempts to override the Bootstrap default colors. I'm focused on the variables.scss file, but maybe something else is wrong.

This is how I set everything up:

```
npm create svelete@latest myWebApp
cd myWebApp
npm install bootstrap --save
npx svelte-add@latest scss
npm install
```

My ./src/+layout.svelte file looks like:

```
<script>
  import '../app.scss';
  import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
  import scriptSrc from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js?url';
</script>
<svelte:head>
  <script src={scriptSrc}></script>
</svelte:head>
<slot />
```

My ./src/variables.scss file looks like:

```
// *** First Attempt ***
// $primary: #ff0000;
// @import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss'
// **********************


// *** Second Attempt ***
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
$primary: #ff0000;
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
// **********************
```

I should clarify that I'm expecting the "primary" color to change to red, but it remains blue.

Comment: Please refer to this answer where I explain how to correctly configure saas modules and especially the Bootstrap variables one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77814573/354490

Comment: I am guilty of copy/pasting from a tutorial I watched recently. It looks like I might need to understand what I'm doing (imagine that, lol). I'll make some changes and update.